# Variable Not Existing In Current Context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in unity I'm coding a script that takes you to a new scene after 10 seconds pass.
I'm doing it by starting a coroutine. In the IEnumerator that has the same name that the coroutine
has. But and still I have a error saying "The variable X does not exist in the current context" I have no idea why this is happening.

### Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Anim : MonoBehaviour
{
    float X = 1;
    
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(X == 1f)
        {
            IEnumerator Timer()
            {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            float X =- 0;
            }
        }
        
    } 
    
}
```

I was expecting it to load the new scene after 10 seconds have passed but it gave me an error.

Comment: I think The issue with your code is that you have defined Timer method inside the FixedUpdate method. You should move the Timer method outside of FixedUpdate.

Comment: Would you please be so kind to include your code as code, and not an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to call Timer() even though it doesn't exist yet. If I'm not mistaken the Start method is called before the FixedUpdate where you create the IEnumerator.

You should put the part that creates the Timer() either into the Start method above where you call Timer(), or you could put it completly outside of those methods at the same place as X. Then your code should work.

```
void Start()
{
    IEnumerator Timer()
    {
    [...]
    }
    StartCoroutine(Timer());
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
[...]
}
```

or

```
float X = 1;
IEnumerator Timer()
{
    [...]
}

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Timer());
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
[...]
}
```

(I'm not 100% sure which is the best option, I'd probably put it into Start.)

Btw. Try to add your code as text into your question (as I've done above) instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: I sent an image because it said it was not formatted correctly when I put the code in

Comment: @Leon weird... just keep it in mind for the next time. Formatting is: 
```
Code
```

Comment: Thank you so much that problem caused me to be stuck in my game for so long!

Comment: @Leon Your welcome keep in mind to mark my answer if it worked!

Comment: Also how would I manage to put the IEnumerator in a if statement?

Comment: @Leon I don't exactly know why you would want to put it there in the first place. The code you wrote does create a new IEnumerator everytime the if-statement is true. If I'm not mistaken your code wouldn't have done anything except creating infinite IEnumerators. But that is another question anyways and shouldn't be discussed in the comments of this question.

Comment: The reason I want that is because the inumerator loops for some reason